# Website files wont update (even after hard refresh and cleared cache)

Tags: html, css, refresh

I am updating a website template to make it more personal (not deleting anything from the template and still giving credit that is needed to use it, etc.). But I am basically just changing the color in the background image. So, I took the image they had as the background and added a layer and blended them to make it look the way i wanted. Then I saved it as a new image in case anything got screwed up. So the original image was back-top.png and the new one i named back-top2.png .

So, I changed the code from:
background:url(images/back-top.png)

to:
background:url(images/back-top2.png)

and the background goes away entirely. Then I tried to just save the picture as back-top.png (as in I basically updated that file) and now it shows but as the original image.

I have saved the changes and refreshed the page (a few different ways i might add) and ive even cleared my caches and tried it in a couple browsers. I double checked the properties of both images and the only difference is one is about 5 KB bigger.

Any help? I am still learning HTML and website design (which is why I decided to use a template) but I know I didnt change anything too much to make things not work. How can I fix this, PLEASE help!!

Also, I've seen code to put in that will clear the cache when someone visits the site. However, if i physically have cleared my cache and its still not working how would those help? also if they do in some way, where exactly in my code do I put them?

Comment: do you have an example of this error online somewhere?

Comment: I've seen this error when developing with smarty and freeBSD. There was a lot of "noise" files that were being generated by the .tpl file. It required me clearing those hidden noise files off my dev directory.

Comment: You changed the background **from** back-top.png **to** back-top2.png. If the latter doesn't already exist in the same directory as the original, it's correct that the background should go away (because the file doesn't exist). Make sure you saved the image correctly as **back-top2.png**, since that's what your code is looking for (not back-top.png, like your post says - but I think this might be a typo).

Comment: I saved back-top2.png to the same folder that back-top.png was in. 

and what i think you read as a typo was me saying after making a whole new image didnt work i tried to update the original (back-top.png) and saved it as back-top.png in the same place (basically i replaced the yellow image with a red image) and that is when it reverts back to the original yellow image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path for an image used as a CSS background is relative to the CSS file, not relative to the website root.

So if your CSS file is in the **website/css** directory, double check that you are saving the background image to the **website/css/images** directory

Good luck!

**EDIT**

If you place your updated background image in the
http://www.impendingreview.com/wp-content/themes/filmstar/images directory you should be good.

When you've done that you should find the file at
http://www.impendingreview.com/wp-content/themes/filmstar/images/back-top2.png

and edit the stylesheet at http://www.impendingreview.com/wp-content/themes/filmstar/style.css  to something like

```
body {
color: #5c5858;
position: relative;
font-family: 'tahoma';
background: url(images/back-top2.png) repeat-x;
}
```

as you had noted earlier.

Comment: Can you post the URL of the page?

Comment: I'm saving it to exactly where the original image came from. The two images are literally right next to each other in the folder

Comment: The reason I ask is that knowing the URL we can use a web inspector and pinpoint the cause of the problem.

Comment: sorry, this comment thing is so small i miss them. But, the site is impendingreview.com and the yellow/gray background image is the problem. I want it to be red but it wont use the image i uploaded. I also realized that it will work with other images that came with the template but as soon as i modify them the image will disappear. Could it just have to do with the theme?

Comment: I did this. That is where the issue comes in. When I do that it takes away the image entirely. And literally all I did was add that 2 so there should be no way I messed up a period or anything haha. And again, when I modify the original image and save it as the original file "(images/back-top.png)" it brings back the original and not my modified version.

Comment: Thanks @CatrinaRoqueyBailey, are you saying that there should be a file at http://www.impendingreview.com/wp-content/themes/filmstar/images/back-top2.png ?

Comment: im saying that when i made the code images/back-top2.png (with my image, in the same file as the original) the background disappears. But when i update the original background image (the one you see on the site now) and update the code back to images/back-top.png it comes back as the original and not my updated version. If you would like i can revert it to images/back-top2.png and send you the link again so you can see what i mean

Comment: Can you upload the back-top2.png file? No need to change the CSS for now.

Comment: To http://www.impendingreview.com/wp-content/themes/filmstar/images/back-top2.png

Comment: its in the theme's file. But its not showing up in that link. I uploaded it also to my media library but its not showing. the link to the image in the file is (c:\\users\catrina\documents\ImpRev\filmstar\filmstar\images\back-top2.png)

now i see how theres an issue but i dont understand what it is.

Comment: How are you uploading the image to your website? Are you using an FTP program? @CatrinaRoqueyBailey

Comment: its apart of the code from the theme i downloaded. So, it should just be coming from the file

Comment: If you created a custom background image locally on your computer, you will need to upload it to your website. Having it saved locally at c:\\users\... won't do the trick. Do you know how to use and FTP program? Alternatively, what's the URL of the version you upladed to the media library? We could make things work with that copy as well.

Comment: I do not know how to use FTP. the link is http://www.impendingreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/back-top2.png

and thank you so much for being patient with me and helping me out!!

Comment: Thnt's great @CatrinaRoqueyBailey . If everything is solved please click the check mark to the left of the answer. It will save others spending time on it.